# How to remove id and title from url and rewrite it with domain followed by title name only?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I want to remove id from URL and rewrite it with domain followed by title name only for SEO-frendly URL.

```
http://www.eyecatchers.co/testblog1.php?id=110&title=6-Benefits-of-Hiring-a-Digital-Marketing-Agency.
```

This is my current URL and I want to rewrite it through `.htaccess` to following URL

```
http://www.eyecatchers.co/6-Benefits-of-Hiring-a-Digital-Marketing-Agency.
```

I have tried with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule id/(.*)/(.*)/ testblog1.php?id=$1&title=$2 
RewriteRule id/(.*)/(.*) testblog1.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

But it has given me

```
http://www.eyecatchers.co//id/110/6-Benefits-of-Hiring-a-Digital-Marketing-Agency.
```

How can I get domain along with title name only?

Comment: have you tried anything...

Comment: do u use any framework?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski  i have n't use any framework

Comment: Are you sure you need that dot at the end of the url?

Comment: @Tarasovych sorry that was a sentence. Not necessary to have that

Answer (score 0):

This one regex may help
`preg_replace("/testblog1\.php\?id=\d*&title=/", "$1", $input_lines);`

So
`http://www.eyecatchers.co/testblog1.php?id=123&title=your-title`
goes as
`http://www.eyecatchers.co/your-title`

Comment: where to use this ?can you please elaborate it.

Comment: @Swagatika [read here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html). I don't know if you have only one `.htaccess` at your server so I can't give fully answer